# How to make the Python script save inputs?

Tags: python

How can I turn this Python into something that will update the known "birthdays?".

I want it so when I enter an input, it will automatically save so I can refer back the "birthday" that was input again.

```
    birthdays = {'Doge1': 'Apr 1', 'Doge2': 'Dec 12', 'Doge3': 'Mar 4'}
     while True:
     print('Enter a name: (blank to quit)')
     name = input()
      if name == '':
       break
        if name in birthdays:
        print(birthdays[name] + ' is the birthday of ' + name)
       else:
       print('I do not have birthday information for ' + name)
       print('What is their birthday?')
       bday = input()
       birthdays[name] = bday
       print('Birthday database updated.')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to chose a storage option. If you'd like to store any object in a file you could use the cPickle library for Python. If you intend to store a lot of data though I'd suggest a database of course. You could start with SQLite3.

Comment: What would you advise if I just wanted to store a few "birthdays" or something relative to that?

Comment: If you intend to read those birthdays in again after the program has executed, then I would go the SQLite3 route. If not, you could get away with writing text to a file. Based on your response to that question I'll post up an example for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

After `print(birthdays[name] + ' is the birthday of ' + name)`, insert:

```
print('Would you like to update his/her birthday? (y/n)')
update = input()
if update == 'y':
    print('What is his/her birthday?')
    newBirthday = input()
    birthdays[name] = newBirthday
    print('Birthday database updated.')
elif update == 'n':
    break
else:
    print('Invalid Input')
```